# Custom Plugin for wordpress with hierarchy of SEF pages

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Here's my issue.  My company needs a vendor database added to our wordpress website.  None of the existing plugins will even come close to what we need, and we already have a mysql database with all of our information, so we need to create a plugin or something to do what we need.

These urls need to be direct-accessible and have SEF urls.  So, for example:

```
mysite.com/vendors/
mysite.com/vendors/pipe-manufacturers/
mysite.com/vendor/bobs-pipes/
```

And, the custom content needs to appear inside the wordpress template.

There are really 2 options:

1) Find a way to write our application outside of wordpress, but find a way to bootstrap wordpress to show the header, footer, and sidebar.

2) Run the app from inside wordpress.

So I went for option #2.  I created a new template file named "vendor.php", and began working.  I added this code to my functions.php of my theme:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'xyz_template_check' );

function xyz_template_check() {
    global $template;

    $rqst = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $ra = split("/", $rqst);

    if ($ra[1] == "vendors") {

        $template_file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/vendors.php';
        return $template_file;

    }

    return $template;


}
```

So what the above code does, if it sees the word "vendors" as the first part of the url after the site name, it sends you to vendor.php.  This works PERFECTLY....

except...

Wordpress believes that the page is not found.  It returns a 404 header, and NOT FOUND into the page title and breadcrumb.

Adding a PAGE called "Vendor Database" with the permalink "/vendors/" fixes the main page.  But there will be literally hundreds of vendors and different categories.  I cant be creating a custom page for each one.  This needs to be dynamic.

So, how do I make wordpress give a 200, and supply an acceptable page title, breadcrumb, etc.

Don't even get me started on the danged wp_title filter.  This did NOT work as documented.  Although, it just occurred to me that this might be an issue with Wordpress SEO (the wp_title filter issue).

Anyone got an idea on this?

Comment: So, a thought.  Maybe I do have a "page" for each vendor.  I could write a batch job to run through the DB and create a page for each entry in my DB, and then write a piece of code to do all of the DB stuff each time I add/edit/delete a record in our main database.

Besides that, the only other thing I could think of was trying to put all of our data into wordpress as a custom post type, but with all of my requirements I'm sure it would work either.

Nothing from the experts on this?  Even a gentle kick in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got this.  The solution was to use the rewrite api, as mentioned above, to look for the pattern /vendors/, letting it know that it was a valid URL.  Coupled with my existing template override, this is what I needed.